# Undefined reference errors when trying to compile and simple ImageMagick program

Tags: c++, cmake, imagemagick, linker-errors, magick++

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for a long time to no avail.
I am trying to compile this simple program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <Magick++/Image.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    InitializeMagick("D:\\Programming\\CPPProjects\\NoteScripts\\Dependencies\\magick\\include");
    Image image; 
    // image.read("arch");
    // image.write("test.png");
}
```

Upon building, I get the following error:

```
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `Magick::InitializeMagick(char const*)'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::Image()'
CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `Magick::Image::~Image()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From what I can tell, this is a linker error but I have no idea where I am going wrong with linking the libs needed.

I installed ImageMagick on Windows 10 from the [ImageMagick downloads page](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) with this installer: ImageMagick-7.1.0-50-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe

I then copied the lib files from the `lib` folder under the installation directory into my project and then copied the `include` folder under the installtion directory into my project.

Here is what the project hierarchy looks like (Source Directory is `NoteScripts`):

[image]

My `CMakeLists.txt` consists of:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe")
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe" )
# set the project name
project("Notes")

include_directories(D:/Programming/CPPProjects/NoteScripts/Dependencies/magick/include)

# add the executable
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main D:/Programming/CPPProjects/NoteScripts/Dependencies/magick/lib/CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib)
target_link_libraries(main D:/Programming/CPPProjects/NoteScripts/Dependencies/magick/lib/CORE_RL_MagickCore_.lib)
target_link_libraries(main D:/Programming/CPPProjects/NoteScripts/Dependencies/magick/lib/CORE_RL_MagickWand_.lib)
```

If I comment out lines 9 and 10 where `InitializeMagick()` is called and where `Image image` is declared, the program compiles without error. I'm also aware that the order of the static libs listed out matters but trying out multiple combinations has resulted in the same error. I have also verfied the dependency order by sifting through the original source code and the reference path is Magick++ -> MagickCore -> MagickWand.

I am relatively new to the process of adding external dependencies to my C++ projects so this is unfamiliar territory (coming from languages with clean package managers). Any help as to how to fix this issue is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is a pain to setup this thing if you are a newbie like me.

Now to the steps to dynamically link imagemagick libs with your C app:

- go to https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-Windows and follow the instructions there (**Install Visual Studio dependencies** - **Clone the dependencies** - **Build configure.exe**- **Build ImageMagick**)
- in the step **Build configure.exe**, when running **configure.exe**, keep the default option selected when asked about the output library type (keep it set to dynamic)
- in the  **Build ImageMagick** step, when you open `VisualDynamicMT.sln` in visual studio, before you start the `build`, select all the solutions in the project, and right-click -> properties -> General -> C Language Standard -> choose Default (Legacy MSVC). After that, click on the top-most solution that contains all the other 196 solutions, and build it. watch the console for errors, I didn't get any errors with the configuration above.
- After the latter step, go the `VisualMagick` folder (created from steps before), and you will see `lib` folder and `bin` folder. You're done, your `dlls` are in `bin` and your `.lib` file are in `bin` folder. Note that these files will be corresponding to build or release environments depending on what you selected in visual studio at the build step.
- How do you use imagemagick now in your project regardless if you have imagemagick app installed on your pc or not? Lets create a new project in vscode, call it demo.
- Create this project structure:
  [image]
- inside `src` you will put your C code.
- inside `deps` create `ImageMagick/lib` and `ImageMagick/bin` and `ImageMagick/include`
- inside `ImageMagick/include` place the same include files you said you got in your question.
- inside `ImageMagick/lib` place the `.lib` files you got from above
- inside `ImageMagick/bin` place the `.dll` files you got from above
- now add this to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

project(demo-app C)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES src/*.c)

add_executable(demo ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories(src)

# ImageMagick
if(WIN32)
    add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 )
    add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 )
    include_directories(deps/ImageMagick/include)
    target_link_directories(demo PRIVATE deps/ImageMagick/lib)
    file(GLOB IMAGEMAGICK_LIBS deps/ImageMagick/lib/*.lib)
    target_link_libraries(demo 
        "${IMAGEMAGICK_LIBS}"
    )
    add_custom_command(TARGET demo POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
            "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/ImageMagick/bin"
            $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:demo>)
endif()
```

(The `add_custom_command` will copy the `dlls` to your executables path after every build)

- Now write some magick code in you `src` directory.
- `ctrl + shift + A` -> `CMake select kit` -> choose the `Visual Studio community 2022 release -amd64` or change to what fits you if it doesn't work
- `ctrl + shift + A` -> `CMake Clean Rebuild`
- `ctrl + shift + A` -> `CMake run without debugging`

Answer (score 0):

The typical (and easiest) way of handling dependencies in CMake is using its `find_package` command:

```
find_package(ImageMagick REQUIRED COMPONENTS MagickCore MagickWand Magick++)

// ...

target_link_libraries(main ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
```

This method is [available](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindImageMagick.html) for ImageMagick with your CMake version. I'm not familiar with CMake on Windows, but `find_package` by default searches a number of standard (system) locations for the package's files. Since you have a custom setup, it should also be possible to specify a nonstandard [search prefix](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#command:find_package) to the command. Additionally, you could download external dependencies in a portable way with the [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html?highlight=fetch#module:FetchContent) commands.